# MQ COMMAND dspmqver DO

Tags: ibm-mq

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it.
I am running IBM MQ on Solaris.
I tried to find IBM MQ command to find the version of mq but it gives me the following error:

code:

```
        # pwd
        /opt/mqm/bin
        # dspmqver
        AMQ8594: WebSphere MQ commands are no longer available in /usr/bin.

        In order to run MQ commands you must manage your path configuration as
        described in the WebSphere MQ product documentation. In particular review the
        topic on "Choosing a primary installation".
        # sudo dspmqver     
        Sorry, user root is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/dspmqver' as root on ud1981esb31.
```

Comment: /opt/mqm/bin/dspmqver should work

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues with what you were attempting to do.

First, you did not put the path of /opt/mqm/bin/ in the $PATH environment variable, so when you attempted to run dspmqver command, it is picking up something (shell script I think) that the installer put in the /usr/bin/ directory.

Secondly, if you want to run a program from the current directory you need to prefix it with './' (it's a Unix/Linux thing).

i.e.

```
./dspmqver
```

> Sorry, user root is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/dspmqver' as root
> on ud1981esb31.

Third, you should never ever start a queue manager or run other MQ commands as 'root'.  It should be done under the 'mqm' account.